# Using prepareForSegue to pass data to ViewController later in app

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I was wondering, when passing data using prepareForSegue, can you pass data to a View Controller later in the app? For example on the first ViewController I have the user enter their name. It's not until the very end, so a few views later, do I need to display their name. Is there a way to pass their name without having to go to the end view right away?

Comment: user defaults are perfect for this!

Comment: User defaults are great. Only complaint is the data is persistent. I'd like it to reset once the app is closed. Thanks for the idea!

Comment: You could reset the user default on start up of the app (didFinishLaunchingWithOptions).

Answer (score 2):

Use a Coordinator.

It's really easy to decouple your ViewControllers:

- instead of using segues give every ViewController a delegate
- create a coordinator object (this object knows your screen flow, not your screens)
- the coordinator creates the ViewControllers (it can use `UIStoryboard  instantiateViewController(withIdentifier:)` so **ViewController A** does not have to know that **ViewController B** exists
- instead of calling `performSegue` you just call your delegate and pass in the data

## Benefits

- Simple to use
- Easy to reorder screens in a flow
- Highly decoupled (easier testing)
- Very nice for A/B testing
- Scales a lot (you can have multiple coordinators, one for each flow)

## Sample

Let's say you have 3 VCs, the first one asks for your name, the second for your age and the third displays the data. It would make no sense that `AgeViewController` knew that `NameViewController` existed, later on you may want to change their order or even merge them.

### Name View Controller

```
protocol NameViewControllerDelegate: class {
    func didInput(name: String)
}

class NameViewController: UIViewController {
    weak var delegate: NameViewControllerDelegate?

    @IBOutlet var nameTextField: UITextField!
    //Unimportant stuff ommited

    @IBAction func submitName(sender: Any) {
        guard let name = nameTextField.text else {
            // Do something, it's up to you what
            return
        }

        delegate?.didInput(name: name)
    }
}
```

### Age View Controller

```
protocol AgeViewControllerDelegate: class {
    func didInput(age: Int)
}

class AgeViewController: UIViewController {
    weak var delegate: AgeViewControllerDelegate?

    @IBOutlet var ageTextField: UITextField!
    //Unimportant stuff ommited

    @IBAction func submitAge(sender: Any) {
        guard let ageString = ageTextField.text,
              let age = Int(ageString) else {
                // Do something, it's up to you what
            return
        }

        delegate?.didInput(age: age)
    }
}
```

### Displayer View Controller

```
class DisplayerViewController: UIViewController {
    var age: Int?
    var name: String?
}
```

### Coordinator

```
class Coordinator {
    var age: Int?
    var name: String?

    var navigationController: UINavigationController

    init(navigationController: UINavigationController) {
        self.navigationController = navigationController
    }

    fileprivate lazy var storyboard: UIStoryboard = {
        return UIStoryboard(name: "MyStoryboard", bundle: nil)
    }()

    //This works if you name your screns after their classes
    fileprivate func viewController<T: UIViewController>(withType type: T.Type) -> T {
        return storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: String(describing: type(of: type))) as! T
    }

    func start() -> UIViewController {
        let viewController = self.viewController(withType: NameViewController.self)
        viewController.delegate = self

        navigationController.viewControllers = [viewController]

        return viewController
    }
}
```

### Coordinator + Name View Controller Delegate

```
extension Coordinator: NameViewControllerDelegate {
    func didInput(name: String){
        self.name = name

        let viewController = self.viewController(withType: AgeViewController.self)
        viewController.delegate = self

        navigationController.pushViewController(viewController, animated: true)
    }
}
```

### Coordinator + Age View Controller Delegate

```
extension Coordinator: AgeViewControllerDelegate {
    func didInput(age: Int) {
        self.age = age

        let viewController = self.viewController(withType: DisplayerViewController.self)
        viewController.age = age
        viewController.name = name

        navigationController.pushViewController(viewController, animated: true)
    }
}
```

Comment: if you give any link about Coordinator that is really helpful too

Comment: Maybe an example would help the OP to actually understand what you're talking about

Comment: I'm writing one, hold tight :)

Comment: There! A simple example. I must add that even though a singleton *may* solve your problem it doesn't scale and will create you more problems in the future.

Answer (score 1):

Not really. You can pass view by view the item but it's not a proper way of doing things.

I suggest you to have a Static Manager or this kind of stuff to store the information globally in your app to retrieve it later

Comment: Thanks for the response. I thought about passing view by view, but it seems like a messy way to do it. I'm pretty new to Swift and something similar to a class in Java to store data would really help, I'd think.

Comment: Do a search on the Singleton design pattern. ("Swift singleton") A data container singleton would be a decent solution to this situation.

Answer (score -1):

All the solution are pretty good. Possible you can try the below model also

**1. DataModel class**

```
1.1 Should be singleton class
1.2 Declare value
```

**Step 1 : ViewCOntroller-one**

1 Create the Sharedinstance of singleton class
    1.1 Assign the value

**Step 3 :ViewController-two**

1 Create the Sharedinstance of singleton class
    1.1 Get the value